# A reader that requires a user to choose a file

Tags: fme-form

I'd like to add a reader to a canvas, that instead of me already having a certain file that it is using, when run, it will force the user to add in a file.

It seems like when I add readers, I can't continue unless I have a file specified.

I'm very new to FME.

Comment: Have a look at setting the feature types to read as a parameter, so the user must choose the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think a FeatureReader (initiated by a Creator) is probably a bit more intuitive for this kind of job. Then replace the dataset with a published parameter.

Answer (score 1):

So I just wanted to expand on the other comment/answer you have. Both are correct, but if you're new to FME, you might need a little more clarification on why it's like this.

The big question is, will all of the files chosen by the end-user be the same structure (called Schema in FME), or will they be different? Like, will they have the same fields (Attributes) and the same layers (Feature Types)?

Because when you add a reader, you're asked to pick a file because that sets the schema for all future files. You're basically telling FME, "users are going to run this workspace, and this is the schema their files will have." This is called a Static Workspace.

If that's not the case, and each file may be different, then you need to use what's called a Dynamic Workspace. Basically, you press Ctrl+G to generate the workspace and click the option to create Dynamic Workspace.

Then when you pick a file, you're now telling FME, "Here's a file to set up the workspace, but it doesn't really matter because everyone's file will be different anyway."

Either way, as others mentioned, when you add a reader, FME creates a "user parameter" (sometimes called a "published parameter). That means all users who run the workspace in future will be prompted to select the file they want to use.

I hope this is useful. I know as a newbie to FME, it can be a little confusing at first. Check out the FME Academy for learning resources to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Thanks for the detailed response :). Plus I appreciate you explaining all the different terms too. The other answer mentioned a published parameter but I didn't know what that meant. I will start with a Dynamic workspace instead and see how I go. Cheerio and Merry Christmas!